# PowerBI Service POST query with API Key

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a POST query to XSOAR API, /incidents/search endpoint to gather data. I have an API key for this.
In PowerBI desktop, this works just fine:

```
let
   url = "https:/XSOARSERVER/acc_ACCOUNT/incidents/search",
   headers = [#"Accept"="application/json", #"Content-Type"="application/json", #"Authorization"="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"],
   body = {filter={query=""}},
   content = Json.FromValue(body),
   Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers= headers, Content= content]))
in
   Source
```

When I upload this in PowerBI Service, it no longer refreshes. It load for a time and then reports an error:

```
Data source error[ValidateMarkupTags][ccon]DataSource.Error: [ccon]Unable to connect to the remote server[/ccon].
[ccon]https://XSOARSERVER/acc_ACCOUNT/incidents/search[/ccon]. [/ccon];[ccon]Unable to connect to the remote server[/ccon].
The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. Table: Query1.
```

I have tried to use this query instead:

```
let
   url = "https:/XSOARSERVER/acc_ACCOUNT/incidents/search",
   headers = [#"Accept"="application/json", #"Content-Type"="application/json"],
   body = {filter={query=""}},
   content = Json.FromValue(body),
   Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers= headers, Content= content, ApiKeyName = "Authorization"])),
in
   Source
```

With the API key in the credentials, but it won't allow me a POST request that is not anonymous:

```
Web.Contents with the Content option is only supported when connecting anonymously.
```

Is there any way to make this work? Or is it really not possible to have a POST request with API key as data source in PowerBI Service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your URL is an internal one and so not accessible from the web which is where PBI Service is refreshing from. You will need to use a public accessible URL or install the PBI Gateway for which PBI Service can then use to get to your onPrem URL.

[What is an on-premises data gateway?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-onprem)